# What do you call someone who is the "external" contact person for a department or section within a company?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Let's say a company has six different departments: Department A, Department B and so on. At each department, there is one person who serves as an "outward", or "external" contact person, so all communication between departments should go via this contact person. That is, if someone from Department A wants to get help with something from Department B, they contact Department B's "external" contact person, who will then take the matter to the right person within Department B. What do you call this person? *External contact person*? *Outward contact person*? *Entry contact person*? What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a person is often called a "point of contact". If you want to emphasize that this POC is only for external relations, then I can't think of a better way of saying that except explicitly, e.g.:

> He/she is our point of contact for external (or in this case perhaps "interdepartmental") relations.

Comment: Thank you!! YES!! This is exactly the expression I was after! It was hiding somewhere in the back of my mind, but I just couldn't find it :)) Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to call that person the "public face", whether of a department or an entire company. I believe this usage is fairly recent however (as in the last decade or two).

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, but that's not *quite* what I was after. MarcinManhattan solved it for me though :) Thanks anyway :)